# Join two files keeping the element order of one of them

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I have two files

File1

```
03873
03872
03871
03870
......
```

File2

```
00001    0.867
00002    0.855
00003    0.864
00004    0.855
...
03870    0.825
03871    0.852
03872    0.326
03873    0.852
```

I want to append the values in the II column of `File 2` in `File 1`, keeping the order of element that `File 1` has.

File3

```
03873    0.852
03872    0.326
03871    0.852
03870    0.825
......
```

I could do this with `join`, but I do not want to sort `File 1`. I thought to use `awk`

```
awk -F "\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0; next}$1 in a {print a[$1]"\t"$2}' File1  File2
```

But also in this case I get the data sorted. 
Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `awk` is not sorting. The output is printed in the order it is found in `file2` and *that* is sorted. To keep the order found in `file1`, just inverse it (I also removed the needless `a[$1]"\t"$2`, you were already saving `$0` in `a`):

```
$ awk -F "\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0; next}$1 in a {print a[$1]}' file2 file1 
03873   0.852   
03872   0.326   
03871   0.852   
03870   0.825
```

Comment: @glennjackman why? The OP basically wants those lines from `file2` whose first field is in `file` but in the order they appear in `file1`. At least, that's what I surmise from their desired output. Am I missing something?

Comment: No. Just that file1 does not have a $2, so the OP's code you pasted didn't really make sense anymore.

Comment: @glennjackman ah, yes, of course. Thanks. It should be alright now.